# jquery.shuffleLetters.js file not working in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following is the html code I am using to make jquery work. I would like the phrases on my page shuffle in and then rest as the desired word. For example, the word "DETERMINED" comes in as a scramble of actively moving letters and then stops as the DETERMINED. [I got the idea from here.](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/)

```
    <head>
    <title>Erica Roxxx - Web Development and Design</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.shuffleLetters.js"></script>
                <script src="JS/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style_scratch.css" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fonts.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<img src="images/logo_design.png" />
<div class="roxxxFontClass">


<h1>GOD</h1><h1>FAMILY</h1><h1>DESIGN</h1>
<font color="950000" size="5"><p>WEB DEVELOPMENT &amp; DESIGN</p></font>
</div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You are linking 2 JQuery versions on the same page, this will most certainly cause problems with most libraries

Comment: why are you using 2 differenct versions of jQuery?

Comment: Because I dont know what I am doing!!! Duh lol please help direct me because I dont know if thats a statement or a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is **no need of 2 different version of jQuery**

.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var container = $("#container")
// Shuffle the container with custom text
container.shuffleLetters({
    "text": "DETERMINED!"   // Replace the text of element that you want
});
```

**Beware:**

Script ordering is very important.

Better add your css files before your scripts.

1) jQuery library
2) shuffleLetters js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.shuffleLetters.js"></script>
```

Check this for clean [**JSFiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/RCKPr/)

and here one [**JSFiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/RCKPr/1/) with continuous shuffle.